# Can I take a book without reading it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there any way to take/steal a book without opening it?

I want to be able to pick up a skill book without gaining the skill, so that I can read it when I'm at a higher level in the skill, without having to remember where the book is, and go back to it later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was thinking about that the other day. Based on an earlier experience I think you can do it with the help of a companion.

Ask a companion to do something and point him to the book. I think it'll say "Read the book" but do it anyway. He'll just pick/steal it and then take it from his inventory.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer, I'll do some testing to see if it works. I'm hoping that there's an answer that doesn't need a companion though, as I'm yet to find a companion who I like (need to find one with a high sneak skill).

Comment: complete the dark brotherhood quest line and you'll have companions with high sneak.

Comment: Ok, well since this works, and no-one has come up with an answer that can be achieved without a companion, I'm going to accept it.